# como aplicar uma classe css somente em mobile

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou usando a versão mais recente do OpenCart para criar uma loja online, e eu coloquei o carrinho de compras na barra de navegação e eu quero que seja uma dropdown quando é em um desktop e um menu dropup quando está em uma tela menor. Eu era capaz de fazer a parte dropup adicionando a classe "dropup" no código como na imagem abaixo. Eu não criei essa classe Eu só aplicou a partir de inicialização. 
[image: code]

Comment: Por favor não coloque fotos de código.

Comment: Olá Filipe! Por favor veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como melhorar a sua pergunta para que você consiga uma boa resposta para o seu problema! Se puder, cole a parte relevante do seu código e verifique as ferramentas de formatação disponíveis. Além disso, aproveite e faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), vale uma medalha! :D

Answer (score 4):

De forma simples podes deixar o trabalho a cargo do browser através duma Media Query de CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    /* esconde o elemento de controlo caso em Mobile */
    #el-controlo { display: none; }
}
```

Na tua página, adicionas um elemento vazio que vai ficar escondido quando em mobile:

```
<span id="el-controlo"></span>
```

Finalmente, com jQuery adicionas a classe de CSS pretendida caso o teu elemento de controlo esteja oculto:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // se elemento controlo escondido
    if ( $('#el-controlo').css('display')=='none' ) {

        // adiciona classe "dropup"
        $('#meu-elemento').addClass('dropup');
    }
});
```

---

O exemplo em cima pode ser drasticamente reduzido a uma condição de JavaScript recorrendo à [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
if (!window.matchMedia("(min-width: 760px)").matches) {
    $('#meu-elemento').addClass('dropup');
}
```